# Tooltip behind modal dialog

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

How to check these kinds of problem. When i checked the menus i have for a desktop application, some shows proper display of tooltip for close button which should always be at the front. But some are displayed at the back of the modal dialog.

Screenshot of the bug:
 [image: Tooltip_issue]

I kind of have the same problems as the one who posted this: https://coderanch.com/t/460688/java/Glasspanes-tooltips

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class GlassPaneContent extends JPanel {

    GlassPaneContent() {
        setSize(200, 50);
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        JButton button = new JButton("A button");
        button.setToolTipText("A tooltip");
        add(button);

    }
}

class GlassPane extends JPanel {

    private static final Color BG_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 96);
    private GlassPaneContent content = new GlassPaneContent();

    public GlassPane() {
        setLayout(null);
        setOpaque(false);
        add(content);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(BG_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        int x = (getWidth() - content.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - content.getHeight()) / 2;
        content.setLocation(x, y);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        GlassPane gp = new GlassPane();
        getRootPane().setGlassPane(gp);
        gp.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

We're using JAVA Swing. Kindly comment below if ever i need to post the codes. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        GlassPane gp = new GlassPane();
        setContentPane(gp);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much. I just want to ask because i really am new to java swing. What was the difference of using  setContentPane(gp) to getRootPane().setGlassPane(gp)?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! The problem was that since you were using `setGlassPane(gp)`, your JPanel implementation works as a layer on top of the gui. With the `paintComponent` method you draw a rectangle (so this part will no longer be transparent) on the glasspane so that it's above the tooltip hiding it. For more information please check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html